# How does one tell the difference between long and short syllables?

Tags: poetry, meter

Limericks normally use a meter consisting of a long syllable followed by two short syllables, or vice versa.

My question is, how do you differentiate? Is it by ear? I'm a native speaker but my experience with poetry and meter is very lacking.

Comment: Aren't all syllables the same length, one syllable?

Comment: No, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_syllable

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist. But "TheIrishGuy" asking for help with a limerick? I am from NC and don't ask for help dropping my g's.

Comment: Don't be shy, @JeffSahol. We can help with that, too.

Comment: Hi, TheIrishGuy. I edited the first paragraph of your question to make it more succinct, but I think the second paragraph also needs clarification. Specifically, when you ask "how do you differentiate?" do you mean "how do you differentiate between one long and two short syllables?" or "how do you differentiate between limericks that follow the long-short-short pattern and limericks that follow the short-short-long pattern?" or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better expressed as "Stressed" vs. "Unstressed".  Take the classic limerick starter, "There once was a man from Nantucket".   When you speak the line, the emphasis naturally falls onto certain syllables:

> *there ONCE was a MAN from nanTUCKet*

which looks like

> da DA da da DA da da DA da

which is a nice repeating pattern.
If you try to substitute Timbuktu for Nantucket, the pattern of the emphasis is destroyed:

> *there ONCE was a MAN from TIMbukTU*
>
> da DA da da DA da DA da DA

As a native speaker, you should have no trouble determining that "Nantucket" fits the stress pattern called for in the standard limerick form, and "Timbuktu" does not.

Comment: Ok, so by ear. I got it. Appears to be something with experience I should get it. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for nice choice of Timbuktu to reverse the stress pattern of Nantucket

Comment: +1 for NOT finishing the Nantucket limerick

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of a limerick seems to me to be more a matter of timing and rhythm than stress or heavy/light syllables:

```
4 beats -- triplet triplet triplet beat
4 beats -- triplet triplet triplet beat
2 beats -- triplet beat
2 beats -- triplet beat
4 beats -- triplet triplet triplet beat
```

As is ordinary in Western music, there can be preliminary notes whose time is stolen from the previous measure.

The closest I could come to putting a name to this rhythm is an Irish slip jig.  Here are a couple of examples from Youtube:

[Slip jig Irish dance music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb-M0yDjTiE)

[Hunt School of Irish Dance Slip Jig Routine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDIZ6lsCKtg)

Answer (score -1):

There is indeed something known as long vs. short syllables. It is a borrowing from Latin and Greek poetry. Any syllable with a long vowel, any syllable with a dipthong, any syllable with a short vowel followed by more than one consonant, is a "long syllable" - as in, it literally takes longer to pronounce. These are also known as "heavy syllables" as opposed to "light syllables." The Latin form terms were "longum" and "brevis."

For instance, "am" is a short syllable. "Arm" is a long one. "Aim" is a long syllable. And the first syllable of "Amy" is a long syllable. This is not the same thing as stressed vs. unstressed syllables though I think it is natural for the two phenomena to interact.

However I've never heard that a limerick pays attention to long and short syllables, only to stressed and unstressed. If it is true that a limerick is supposed to be written with attention to long and short syllables, I would be interested in who says so and why.

Comment: These are the rules for syllable length in the Latin language, and have nothing to do with English.